# installing R in UBUNTU 16

Tags: r, linux, bash, ubuntu

Steps I followed:

1. add R repo: `sudo echo "deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list`
2. add keys: `gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key E084DAB9`

Result after using 2nd command

> ```
> gpg: requesting key E084DAB9 from hkp server subkeys.pgp.net 
> gpgkeys: key E084DAB9 can't be retrieved
> gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found. 
> gpg: Total number processed: 0 
> gpg: keyserver communications error: keyserver helper general error 
> gpg: keyserver communications error: unknown pubkey algorithm 
> gpg: keyserver receive failed: unknown pubkey algorithm
> ```

I searched for the problem and I tried:

- Since I am using proxy so I have added `export http_proxy=http://username:password@10.1.1.16:80` and `export https_proxy=https://username:password@10.1.1.16:80` in `bash.bashrc`.

> Still Same error

- Problem may be due to firewall: I have change `port number`

> Still Same error

- Manually copy the key

> ```
> Version: SKS 1.1.5
>
> Comment: Hostname: pgp.mit.edu
>
> mQGiBEXUFiURBADkTqPqcRYdLIguhC6fnwTvIxdkoN1UEBuPR6NYW4iJzvRSas/g5bPo5ZxE
> 2i5BXiuVfYrSk/YiU+/lc0K6VYNDygbOfpBgGGhtfzYfFRTYNq8QsdD8L8BMYtOu5rYo5BYt
> a0vuantIS9mn9QnH7885uy5tX/TXO7ICYVHxnFNr2wCguNtMdz9+DRQ38n4iiHzTtj/7UHsD
> /0+0TLHHvY1FfakVinamR9oCm9uH9PmkGTy6jRnrvg5Z+TTgygiDdTBKPc1TqpFgoFtqh8G5
> DpDPbyh5GzBj8Ky1mBJb3bMwy2RUth1cztHEWI36xuCl+KrLtA4OYuCwJJZhOWDIO9aO2LW5
> kJhIwIuvSrEtOgTxpzy82g7eEzvLBADUrQ01fj+9VDrO2Vept8jtaGK+4kW3cBAG/UbOrTjt
> 63VurXwyvNb6q7hKFUaVH42Fc0e64F217mutCyftPWYJwY4SR8hUmjEM/SYcezUDWWvVxmkF
> 8M4rMhHa0j+q+et3mTKwgxehQO9hLUqRebnmJuwNqNJKb9izsPqmh83Zo7Q7Sm9oYW5uZXMg
> UmFua2UgKENSQU4gRGViaWFuIGFyY2hpdmUpIDxqcmFua2VAdW5pLWJyZW1lbi5kZT6IRgQQ
> EQIABgUCRdQ+nQAKCRAvD04U9kmvkJ3+AJ4xLMELB/fT1AwtR1azcH0lKg/TegCdEvtp3SUf
> aHP3Jvg2CkzTZOatfFuIRgQQEQIABgUCS4VoCgAKCRDvfNpxC67+5ZFyAKCAzgPTqM6sSMhB
> iaZbNCpiVtwDrQCgjMy+iqPm7SVOCq0XJsCCbxymfB+IXgQTEQIAHgUCRdQWJQIbAwYLCQgH
> AwIDFQIDAxYCAQIeAQIXgAAKCRAG+Q3lOBukgM09AKCuapN6slttAFRjs2/mgtaMMwO9sgCf
> ZD2au39Oo8QLXZhZTipN8c7j9mM=
> =BRgm
> ```

and save it to a file `jranke_cran.asc`.

Then add apt key using `sudo apt-key add jranke_cran.asc`

error

> gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.

I have tried a lot and still unsuccessful. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you retrieve other keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `gpg` cannot access the key server,
most probably you have a proxy configuration issue.

According to this [other post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36507/how-do-i-import-a-public-key), the correct key is a bit different from what you posted:

```
Public Key Server -- Get ``0x51716619e084dab9 ''

-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: SKS 1.0.10
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=BF1w
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

Save this to a file and import with `sudo apt-key add`. It should work.

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.06  sudo apt-get update shows W: GPG error: http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1445181253  KEYEXPIRED 1445181253  KEYEXPIRED 1445181253
W: The repository 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.